# product is not added to my collection

Tags: node.js, rest, http, express

In my project I have 2 models: Store and product, basically every store can have a number of products, but each product can be related to 1 store, so to build the models I did this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var lojasSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  nome: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  descricao: {
    type: String,
    default: "No description for this store"
  },
  telefone:{
    type:String,
  },
  password:
  {
    type: String, required: true
  }
  ,
  img: {
    data: Buffer, contentType: String
  },
  imgNome: {
    type: String
  },
  produtos: [
    { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Produto' }
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Loja', lojasSchema);
```

**my product is like this**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var produtoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    nome:{
        type:String, required:true
    },
    stock:{
        type:Number
    },
    descricao:{
        type:String
    },
    categoria:{
        type: String, required:true
    },
    tamanho:{
        type: String, required:true
    },
    data:{
        type: Date, default: Date.now
    },
    preco:{
        type: Number,required:true, default: 0
    }
});


 module.exports = mongoose.model('Produto',produtoSchema);
```

as you guys can see I have the reference on the store side, basically what I want is every time I add a product I add that product directly to a store(storeID), so to do that I added this to my store side routes:

```
//adiciona um produto a uma loja especifica
router.post('/:id/produtos',function(req,res){
    Loja.findById(req.params.id,function(err,loja){
      if(!loja){
        return res.status(404).json({Error:"Loja nao encontrada"});
      }

      if(JSON.stringify(req.body) == "{}")
      {
        return res.status(400).json({Error:"Your request is empty"});
      }

      var produto = new Produto(req.body);
      loja.produtos.push(produto);

      loja.save(function(err){
        if(err){
          return res.status(500).json({Error:"Server problem"});
        }
         res.status(200).json({message: "product added"});
      });
    })
})
```

I got 2 problems: when I go to my get products route, I get an empty array, I should get there all the products, I think the product is not getting added in the product's model, the second problem is: every time I add a product to my store, and go to see all my stores with the .populate I just can see an id inside the products array, I should see all the product details, what am I doing wrong?:S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update you mongoose to 4.8.1 because 4.7.6 is buggy with casting Ids.

then go to your lojas.js and require mongoose at the top.

Replace your code with this

```
        router.post('/:id/produtos',function(req,res){

        var queryObject = {_id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)};
        Loja.findById(queryObject,function(err,loja){
                console.log(err);
          if(!loja){
            return res.status(404).json({Error:"Loja nao encontrada"});
          }

          if(JSON.stringify(req.body) == "{}")
          {
            return res.status(400).json({Error:"Your request is empty"});
          }

          var produto = new Produto(req.body);
          produto.save(function (err) {
            if(err){
              return res.status(500).json({Error:"Server Problem"})
            }
              loja.produtos.push(produto._id);

             loja.save(function(err){
            if(err){
              return res.status(500).json({Error:"Server problem"});
            }
             res.status(200).json({message: "product added"});
          });
          });

        })
    })
```

Comment: still no product saved in product doc?

Comment: right, can't get it why at this moment :S, can i add it to github and you give a check this is really frustrating me atm :S

Comment: sure add it to the github

Comment: lojas.js route watch there

Comment: no code init just the router.get('/',function(req,res){
  
});

Comment: what is the problem? i dind't understood

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134896/discussion-between-asif-saeed-and-filipe-costa).